# PHP file_get_contents to read from string

Tags: php, file-handling

So I am using the Solr client library Solarium PHP to control my Solr server. I want to index PDF documents which I download previously from my website. Since the website is huge, I wrote a crawler which uses the `curl_multi_*` functions to fetch the content. Now, I noticed that Solarium uses the following function internally to build up the request to post the PDF file to the Solr server, in `solariumphp/vendor/solarium/solarium/src/Core/Client/Adapter/AdapterHelper.php`:

```
    public static function buildUploadBodyFromRequest(Request $request): string
    {
        $baseName = basename($request->getFileUpload());
        $body = "--{$request->getHash()}\r\n";
        $body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'.$baseName.'"';
        $body .= "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= file_get_contents($request->getFileUpload(), 'r');
        $body .= "\r\n--{$request->getHash()}--\r\n";

        return $body;
    }
```

The obstacle is now the line containing `file_get_contents()`, because actually the post content is not present as file but as string (it is already downloaded). I thought about working with streams (something like `mem://`), but I could not find out how to do it. May someone please help? If this is really not possible, I can pass the URL of the PDF file (and not download it previously), but then I lose some of the ability of parallel downloading from the website. Another ugly solution would be to save the downloaded files temporarily using `file_put_contents` beforehand, but I really do not want to do that.

Comment: If you wanted to change anything about this without modifying the shown code - well then you could only modify what `$request->getFileUpload()` returns to begin with, and that would probably be an equally bad idea.

Comment: @CBroe `$request->getFileUpload()` returns a string variable which I set beforehand (it should be the filename), so that's not the problem if the file can be named like `mem://something`.

Comment: I guess you could try to write the file content to `php://memory` first, and then pass `'php://memory'` as parameter value. The `filename` part of your response headers would always be `memory` then though.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function for similar problems:

```
// simulate a file from given string
// return string fileName
function virtualFile(string $content):string
{
   return 'data://text/plain,'.urlencode($content);
}
```

Works great with file_get_contents too. A little test:

```
$myString = "abc"; 

$fileName = virtualFile($myString);

$myStringCopy = file_get_contents($fileName);

//test
var_dump($myString === $myStringCopy);  //bool(true)
```

Try self on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8D7ak).